# While loop in Bash script not executing from Pre-session command in Informatica

Tags: bash, while-loop, informatica, informatica-powerexchange

I have a completely working bash script to download all the sftp files, convert the .xlsx files to .csv and remove the .xlsx files. It works in linux environment. But while calling the same script through pre-session command in informatica workflow, The while(which converts the .xlsx to csv files) loop is being skipped and only files are being downloaded.
you can see the below error,"The indirect input file does not contain file names" because it is inside the while loop.

[image]

[image: Log]

```
    #!/bin/bash

    export Src_Dir=/path/

    File1=/path/*.*
    DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
    Host_Name=username@hostname
    Pass_Pwd='paswword'
    PORT=22


    cd "$Src_Dir" || { echo 'Failed to chdir into $Src_Dir' ; exit 0; }

    /usr/bin/expect<<EOD


    spawn /usr/bin/sftp -o Port=${PORT} username@hostname
    expect "password:"
    send "$Pass_Pwd\r"
    expect "sftp>"
    send "lcd ${Src_Dir}\r"
    expect "sftp>"
    send "mget ${File1}\r"
    expect "sftp>"
    send "mget ${File1}\r"
    expect "sftp>"
    send "bye\r"
    EOD
    echo "Download done"


    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
        ssconvert "$file" --export-type=Gnumeric_stf:stf_csv
        ls *.csv > Filenames.txt
    done < <(find "$Src_Dir" -type f -iname "*.xlsx" -print0)

    rm *.xlsx
exit 0
```

Comment: Can you check if the user running Informatica processes can locate the `ssconvert` command ? You could make a Command in a Workflow like `which ssconvert > /path/output.txt 2>&1` to find out. If it's positive, you will have the complete path to `ssconvert` in `/path/output.txt`, if it's negative you will find an error message in that file. You can also check that the directory containing `ssconvert` is in the environment variables of Integration Service using the Administration Console, and update the value if necessary.

Comment: i have executed the workflow as you have directed Mickael, the output.txt says /usr/bin/ssconvert.

Comment: I am also trying in an alternate way of trying to execute the while loop in the pre-session command seperatly instead in the bash script. I couldn't find any leads online. Is it actually possible?

Comment: In your script above, the `#!/bin/bash` is not the first line of the script. It must be the first for the script to be run by `bash`. Informatica starts commands with `/bin/sh -c "<command>"` and `/bin/sh` may behave differently or not execute `bash` specific syntax commands. (Doc : https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/data-services/10-2/developer-workflow-guide/command-task/command-syntax.html )

Comment: But I have commented the first line #test purpose only , but anyways I have removed it and made #!/bin/bash the first line of the script. Still the same error Mickael.

Comment: Now the exit code -1 error has been resolved because I have replaced the exit 1 to exit 0,and its fixed,but the while loop isn't executing like usual.

Comment: As Informatica doesn't capture the output of the script, we can't see the real cause of the problem. You could add a command to redirect the script output just before the `while` loop : `exec > /path/script.log 2>&1` (Redirect may interfere with `expect`). Maybe we will see if some program outputs a useful error message...

Comment: Hey Mickael, I already did that in the pre-session command itself. ksh /path/ActivationFlowPrepaid.ksh > /path/Actv_ksh.log 2>&1 seems that it isn't capturing anything useful. Please find the screenshot of the log in the question above.